# Difference between using InsertLogical & accumulate

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I was taking a look at different ways to formulate a constraint rule for Optaplanner. I was wondering about the use of InsertLogical.

In the  [nurse rostering example](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringConstraints.drl), is it just a way to measure the length of the consecutive working days? I mean, I'd like to know the difference between using InsertLogical (and then calculating the day length) or plain and simple "accumulate" function.

Also, about this specific example I'd like to know why is perfomance improved by applying different saliences.

Comment: Accumulate will let you find a collection/group at a point in time, while insertLogical allows you to backtrack while doing decisions since the inserted fact is removed from working memory once the conditions which led to its insertion are no longer true. This also explains why saliences increase performance -- they're used to control the order that rules fire, so if you're constantly backtracking because your insertLogical facts are no longer valid, this is obviously slower so you'd want to reorder your rules to force them to fire in a more logical order.

Answer (score 1):

`insertLogicals` are dreadfully slow. Out of 30 examples/quickstarts or so, nurse rostering is the only one using it, for the "n consecutive" constraints. Avoid it if you can.

For ConstraintStreams, we're working on better, faster, cleaner alternatives to handle these kind of constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your tips and info. I am dealing with a problem similar to the nurse rostering problem. The main difference is that there is no built-in hard constraint for "all shifts must be covered" since some shifts may not be. Therefore I was trying to reformulate my score drl file for the "minimum number of consecutive shifts" constraint to work. Entities are only initialized if I state a !=null positive constraint. However this leads to assigned consecutive shifts with a length below the minimum.

Comment: Is there a way to make CH assign the shifts by a minimum of two consecutive shifts for example whithout them necesarily being multiples of 2?